# Unable to find project key?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, sonarqube

When i was associating with sonar i am getting an error as "project 'addition' with key 'addition:addition' not found on server".Can any one give solution to solve this problem and also suggest steps how to solve it.

Comment: please can any one help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar Eclipse plugin assumes there is already a project created in Sonar, created by one of the standard build plugins (Maven, ANT, Build runner)

The Sonar work-flow assumes that you run Sonar centrally against the project's codebase. It does not support parallel executions (more than one developer running Sonar at the same time). This is a fair assumption as normally Sonar would be executed from a continuous integration server like Jenkins.

The Eclipse plugin is designed to support developers who might be working in parallel on code contained in local Eclipse workspaces. This code may not yet be committed or merged meaning it would be incorrect to upload analysis results to the Sonar server. Instead Sonar analysis is run locally, enabling a developer to see the results of code fixes that might address Sonar violations.